# Outlook: automatically choose a different signature if I am part of the thread

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-signature

I have Outlook 2010. I have set a business signature that is quite verbose like:

```
Name Surname
Company, Inc.
name.surname@company.com

Street Address
Phone +39 000 000 000
Fax +39 000 000 000

This message is strtictly confidential... (about 3 lines)
```

I know I can set a secondary default signature for answering messages, like just:

```
Name Surname
Company, Inc.
```

I am able to add the secondary signature automatically any time I reply to/forward a message. It is my wish to instead use the primary signature when replying, if none of the messages in the thread are mine (i.e. already signed with my primary signature). The purpose is to show full contact info only once in a thread without making it heavyweight. Otherwise on composing a message, the "first signature" is used.

I want Outlook to automatically add my "secondary" signature if it detects that a message of mine is included in the thread.

I have found no option about that. I know I can choose my preferred signature among many every time I compose a message, but I want to ask if that is possible automatically given my "rule" or do I have to manually add the signature I prefer to each message with the Signature button.

To clarify, here is what I want Outlook to do without my intervention:

1. If I compose a new message, the "complete signature" is used.
2. If I receive a new message from a person and reply to it, the full signature is used again.
3. If the message at point 2 receives a reply, and I reply again to that (my original message is included in the thread), the reduced signature is used.

AFAIK Outlook rules cannot modify outgoing messages.

Comment: I have not used outlook 2010 yet, but in 2003 you can easily change the signature if you use word as en editor (it does not work if you use the build-in editor) and the signature starts with the proper dash dash space newline.  Click on the signature and you get to choose between both of your signature options.

Comment: @Hennes I haven't got that. Do you just mean I have to select the proper signature manually when composing each message? I was asking for an automated way, **if that was ever possible**

Answer (score 0):

Dig into the settings, find `Mail`, then `Signatures`. You can create multiple signatures there. On the right, there are text boxes that say `New messages` and `Replies/forwards`. Set the `Replies/forwards` to the short format and you should be all set.

Comment: Sorry, I know about that. Perhaps the question needs to be rephrased